# No of Days between two dates in python 2.4

Tags: python, strptime

This will work in python 2.6

```
from datetime import datetime
print (datetime.strptime('2008-12-31', "%Y-%m-%d")- datetime.strptime('2007-04-30',"%Y-%m-%d")).days
```

But in 2.4 shows following error

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'
```

Thank you for all your Support.

from datetime import date
    from time import strptime

```
x=  strptime('2008-12-31', "%Y-%m-%d")
y=  strptime('2007-04-30', "%Y-%m-%d")

print (date(x.tm_year,x.tm_mon,x.tm_mday)- date(y.tm_year,y.tm_mon,y.tm_mday)).days
```

Comment: The docs say strptime is "New in version 2.5.". So you either need to upgrade, or write code to parse the dates manually. **EDIT:** You could try in the `time` library: http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 2.4 strptime is located in time module:

```
from time import strptime
```

See http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/lib/module-time.html